# Imagemagick - don't know how to solve

Tags: php, image-processing, text, imagemagick, gd

I've got a problem with Imagemagick - constant distance and fontsize dependent by string lenght. Form:

```
 <form action="text.php" method="post">

  <div class="container">
    <label for="uname"><b>Tekst1</b></label>
    <textarea id="confirmationText" class="text" name="primarytext"></textarea>
<br /> <br />
    <label for="psw"><b>Tekst2</b></label>
        <textarea id="confirmationText" class="text" name="secondarytext"></textarea>
<br /><br />
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

// Variables
$text2 = $_POST['secondarytext'];
$text = $_POST['primarytext'];

// Primary image
$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(970, 946, new ImagickPixel('white'));
$image->setImageFormat('png');

// First parameters for text
if(isset($text)){
$len = mb_strlen($text);
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
$draw->setFont('Bookman-DemiItalic');
if ($len < 10){ 
    $fontSized = 70 - (2*$len + 5);  
} elseif($len >= 10 && $len < 50){ 
    $fontSized = 55 - ($len + 4);
} else { 
    $fontSized = 100 - $len; 
}
$fontSized = max($fontSized, 1);
$draw->setFontSize($fontSized);
$draw->setTextAlignment(\Imagick::ALIGN_CENTER);
$image->annotateImage($draw, 485, 473, 0, $text);
}


// Second parameters for text
if(isset($text2)){
$len2 = mb_strlen($text2);
$draw2 = new ImagickDraw();
$draw2->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);
$draw2->setFont('Bookman-DemiItalic');
if ($len2 < 10){ 
    $fontSized2 = 50 - (2*$len2 + 5);  
} elseif($len2 >= 10 && $len2 < 50){ 
    $fontSized2 = 40 - ($len2 + 4);
} else { 
    $fontSized2 = 60 - ($len2 - 2); 
}
$fontSized2 = max($fontSized2, 3);
$draw2->setFontSize($fontSized2);
$draw2->setTextAlignment(\Imagick::ALIGN_CENTER);
$image->annotateImage($draw2, 485, 270, 180, $text2);
$image->annotateImage($draw2, 485, 676, 0, $text2);
}

//Print image on browser
header('Content-type: image/png');

//Save final image
//$image->writeImages($image, true);

//Show image
echo $image;
```

I will paste a image, what is wrong with my generator and what should it be.
Now fontsize is dependent by strlen, but I've got textarea so text can be multiline, so fontsize is set by all variables strlen, I tried with the longest line, but it also don't work - for example:

> S
>   T
>   A
>   C
>   K

Fontsize was too big, because the longest line is only one digit.
I tried to do tftboximage, but function was wrong (function created image dependent by size of all letters - without undue border).

[image: myversion]

[image: targetversion]

Target version looks like have automatic resizer (text is no bigger than 350x210px on center and 190x110px on top/lower text)

Answer (score 1):

You're two characters too high, because you're not calculating the baseline correctly.
The *annotateImage* method moves the first line baseline to the given Y coordinate. However in case of 180 degree rotation the baseline is still at the same position in relation to the original text and not on top of the flipped text.

[image]